# VVV, custom site url redirecting to dashboard

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I've just installed and setup VVV with Vagrant and Virtual Box, everything at the base level is working perfectly.

I've tried adding a custom site, as per their example, but when I navigate to the custom sites' URL(vvvtest.dev) I get sent to the VVV dashboard instead of the WP install process for the new site.

I'm using vagrant-hostsupdater so the hosts file is getting populated for me as well as vagrant-triggers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I've noticed in my hosts file that vvvtest.dev is pointing to the same location(sim link?) as vvv and vvv.dev, see screenshot. Where have I gone wrong during config ?

My vvv-custom.yml file stored in the main folder (vagrant-local):

```
sites:
  # The wordpress-default configuration provides a default installation of the
  # latest version of WordPress.
  wordpress-default:
    repo: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/vvv-wordpress-default.git
    hosts:
      - local.wordpress.dev

  # The wordpress-develop configuration is useful for contributing to WordPress.
  wordpress-develop:
    repo: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/vvv-wordpress-develop.git
    hosts:
      - src.wordpress-develop.dev
      - build.wordpress-develop.dev

  # Custom Install Test
  vvvtest:
    hosts:
      - vvvtest.dev    

  # The following commented out site configuration will create a standard WordPress
  # site in www/example-site/ available at http://my-example-site.dev.

  #example-site:
  #  repo: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/custom-site-template.git
  #  hosts:
  #    - my-example-site.dev

  # The following commented out site configuration will create a environment useful
  # for contributions to the WordPress meta team:

  #wordpress-meta-environment:
  #  repo: https://github.com/WordPress/meta-environment.git

utilities:
  core:
    - memcached-admin
    - opcache-status
    - phpmyadmin
    - webgrind
```

My nginx.conf file stored in www/vvvtest/provision:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name vvvtest.dev;
  root {vvv_path_to_site};

  error_log {vvv_path_to_site}/log/error.log;
  access_log {vvv_path_to_site}/log/access.log;

  set $upstream {upstream};

  include /etc/nginx/nginx-wp-common.conf;
}
```

My vvv-init.sh file, stored in www/vvvtest/provision

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add the site name to the hosts file
echo "127.0.0.1 ${VVV_SITE_NAME}.local # vvv-auto" >> "/etc/hosts"

# Make a database, if we don't already have one
echo -e "\nCreating database '${VVV_SITE_NAME}' (if it's not already there)"
mysql -u root --password=root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${VVV_SITE_NAME}"
mysql -u root --password=root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${VVV_SITE_NAME}.* TO wp@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'wp';"
echo -e "\n DB operations done.\n\n"

# Nginx Logs
mkdir -p ${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}/log
touch ${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}/log/error.log
touch ${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}/log/access.log

# Install and configure the latest stable version of WordPress
cd ${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}
if ! $(wp core is-installed --allow-root); then
  wp core download --path="${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}" --allow-root
  wp core config --dbname="${VVV_SITE_NAME}" --dbuser=wp --dbpass=wp --quiet --allow-root
  wp core multisite-install --url="${VVV_SITE_NAME}.local" --quiet --title="${VVV_SITE_NAME}" --admin_name=admin --admin_email="admin@${VVV_SITE_NAME}.local" --admin_password="password" --allow-root
else
  wp core update --allow-root
fi
```

Hosts File:
[image: Windows Hosts File]

Answer (score 0):

In your www/vvvtest/provision/nginx.conf file, maybe you can try to revise the directory of root to:

```
  root {vvv_path_to_site}/public_html;
```

Hope it helps.